# Which MSE (total or individual) back-propagate for multi out regression neural network

Tags: mlp, mse

When we have multi output regression neural network, we can calculate total MSE and individual MSE per output. How this MSE should back-propagate ? Shouldn't we back-propagate individual MSE through the network for relevant weight.